# PostgreSQL count occurrences of dates in a column that holds an Array of dates within a specified date range

Tags: arrays, postgresql, date, count, unnest

Given a SQL table that has a column, for example 'dates', that holds an array of dates, what query will return every distinct date in the array and the number of times that it occurs? What clause can be added to the query to specify a min and  max date range?

Answer (score 0):

Given 'myTable' with a column that holds an Array of Dates:

```
SELECT count(id), UNNEST(dates) as date
FROM myTable
GROUP BY date;
```

To specify a min date and a max date, for example on or after 2021-01-01 and before 2021-02-01, and sort by date:

```
SELECT count(id), UNNEST(dates) as date
FROM myTable
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM UNNEST(dates) AS x WHERE x>='2021-01-01' AND x<'2021-02-01')
GROUP BY date
ORDER BY date ASC;
```